# Django: Returning a customized view function

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm developing a Django application that will be used by people in various companies. Some companies require highly customized views, which means I'll change the default template depending on their needs. It could also require some extra context variables.

My idea is to create separate view functions as required, since trying to put it all in one view function will get messy quite quickly. For example, let's say I have a dashboard view:

```
def dashboard(request):
    var1 = some_func()
    context = {'var1': var1 }
    return render(request, 'normal_template.html', context)
```

Now company x wants a custom dashboard:

```
def dashboard_for_company_x(request):
    var1, var2 = some_func_x()
    context = {'var1': var1, 'var2': var2 }
    return render(request, 'template_for_x.html', context)
```

So when a user from company x goes to a certain page, dashboard_for_company_x should be used. All other user should use the original dashboard function.

The two options I can think of is either:
1. adding the company's name to the url, so that the URL resolver will use the correct view function.
2. Using middleware to intercept the request and redirect them to the appropriate view function if required.

1 seems like the better option, but it would mean I would to change all the url tags in my template to include the company name, so that is not really an option. I think 2 will work, but seems like a bit of a hack.

Is it fine to use number 2, or are there better options available?

Note that only a small percentage of views will require customization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do the routing inside your view function, e.g.:

```
def dashboard(request):
    if request.user.company == 'foo':
        return dashboard_foo(request)
    elif request.user.company == 'bar':
        return dashboard_bar(request)
    else:
        return dashboard_standard(request)
```

Depending on the complexity of your view it might make sense to use a [class based view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/intro/), so you only need to swap out the specific logic (e.g.: templates, context vars, etc.) in the specific methods, and let the main logic be the same across all users (i.e.: reduce code duplication).